# ruby on rails link_to newly created page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I've created in rails(3) a new html page in my project model named `contact.html.erb` and I am interested in linking to it from a different page, i've added the code:

`<%= link_to 'contact', contact_project_path(@project) %>`

Project is a model that `belongs_to` a User (which is the contact in the contact page).

This link gives me an error message saying that `contact_project_path` doesnt exist. I know I need to define it somewhere but I don't know where or how. I want the page to be specific per project. I've created an action in the `project_controler` named contact and left it empty.

What am i missing?

I've searched for a soloution for quite some time and haven't found an answer to this question anywhere else. I'm aware its a little bit basic but I have no other options.

Comment: please make your post look better...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-REVISED ANSWER-
Based on comments I see you're not trying to associate a contact model, just a view. In that case, you still need to change the routes file, but you need to decide if you want to get a single contact page for all projects, or one contact view per project. IE:

```
# Collection Contact
example.com/projects/contact # IE One contact view for all projects

# Member Contact
example.com/projects/1/contact # IE One contact view per project
```

Either way you need to use a block for your project resource in your routes file. So, if you want there to be one contact page for the collection (all projects), do:

```
resources :projects do
  collection do
    get 'contact'
  end
end
```

Or, if you want one contact view per member (one per project) do:

```
resources :projects do
  member do
    get 'contact'
  end
end
```

Either way this will give you helper methods which you can put into `link_to`

For the collection it should be `contact_projects_path` (no arguments), and for members it should be `contact_project_path(@project)` (pass in the project as an argument.

You can use `get` `post` `put` `delete` or `match` as a parameter in a collection or member block, that just tells Rails what kind of request to handle at that URL, and what helpers to generate. For normal views you want a GET request.

I hope this finally answers your question :)

-ORIGINAL ANSWER-

*This is for routing to a MODEL, not just a view*

Add to your routes.rb:

```
resources :projects do
  resource :contact
end
```

If I understand your question correctly, that should create a helper called project_contact_path().

This record will be `projects/123/contact.`

If you want more than one contact per project, you'll need to make it plural (resource :contacts). Then your records would look like `projects/123/contacts/123`.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

You would link to this using `link_to( project_contact_path(@project) )` if there's only one contact per project, or `link_to( project_contact_path(@project,@contact) )` if there are multiple contacts per project.

Comment: How would i then link to it using `link_to`?

Comment: @nayish: here's a grid of an example of the paths created by nesting comments inside an articles resource: http://i.imgur.com/RhCzR.png. so if you wanted to link to the "show contact" page within a projects resource, you'd use <%= link_to 'contact', project_contact_path(:project_id => @project, :id => @contact) %>. (in that example, you had set @project and @contact in the controller.) Note that the outside resource in the nest comes first in the path and the nested resources comes second.

Comment: The contact page is in the Project view. The contact page gets its user using `@project.user` since it is connected to him using  `belongs_to`. This code therefore can't be used here.

Comment: You would link to it as `project_contact_path(@project)` if it's a singular resource. If there were multiple contacts (ie resources :contacts) you'd have to pass `project_contact_path(@project, @contact)`. I updated the answer to add this note.

Comment: When I enter `project_contact_path(@project)` It tries looking for a Contacts controller, which of course doesn't exist since its just an action. By the way only looking for one contact.

Comment: Ah, ok, my bad... I think you just need to 'get' a contact page for each project, right?

Comment: Exactly, i just need to link to the `contact.html.erb` page

Comment: Ok see totally rewritten answer above. That should do it.

Comment: Just one correction, in your resources function its `get 'contact'` and not `'get' contact`, thanks for all the help

Comment: Heh, you're right. Thanks. If this worked do you mind accepting the answer? (made correction)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

You should be aware that `contact_project_path(@project)` isn't a restful routes (unless contact_project is a model but there is little chance). You'll have to declare this name, use `:as`

Comment: The link you gave doesn't explain about anything but the basic action (new,show,index...) what I'm looking for is a linking to a page I've created. I do not have a contact_project model.